# Detecting if an input field has spawned an autosuggest list?

Tags: javascript, dom

My problem: I have a keyup event attached to a field. If the previously typed autosuggest list appears and you select a value via the keyboard, the keyup event for the field fires. However, I do not want it to fire at this point.

Is it possible to detect if an input field has spawned a previously typed autosuggest list?

When I inspect the field via Firebug after the autosuggest list appears, I don't see a corresponding DOM element. I also do not know of any events associated with autosuggest lists.

Any help is mush appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the browser built-in autosuggest form-fill feature, then no, there is no way to detect it, or interact with it via javascript.

You might be able to cancel it in some browsers via a `event.prevetDefault()`, tho to be honest i haven't tried it, and find it doubtful.

The feature is a convenience feature for the user, and should not concern website operators or developers - leave it alone, and your users will like you better ;)

Comment: Browsers, with minor variations, honor an attribute "autocomplete" set to `false` as indicating that no suggestions should be made. It's common on username/password fields and things like that.

Comment: @Pointy: true, and good point, however i don't think it has much relevance in this case, since the OP is not trying to cancel it, but to trigger js code based on it.

Comment: Yes I was just commenting for posterity :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not trying to suppress or manipulate the built-in autosuggest form-fill feature. I'm trying to listen for the event that triggered it or detect the element that gets rendered. The problem with these... they trigger any keyup events attached to the field if a user selects a suggested value via the keyboard. It would be nice to know if the keyup was the result of selecting a suggested value or the user actually typing a new value.

Comment: @user114781: From javascript point of view, anything selected from an autosuggest list is the same as the user pasting something in to the input field, in other words, there is no real way for you to tell it apart.